# Windows inside virtualbox

Tags: dual-boot, 21.04

I have a laptop with win10 preinstalled. So I have a digital key license.

I have converted my laptop to a dual-boot system with ubuntu 21.04. I want to completely remove windows but install win 10 in a virtualbox. I don't know if my win10 license would be recognised/valid inside a vitualbox installation.

Comment: One way to manage this would be to convert your current Windows partition into a VM image, then use that in VirtualBox. All existing registration and activation keys will be copied over.

Comment: Indeed ^^^. Otherwise you'd be doing a new installation in a "new" (virtualized) hardware platform for which your OEM license ISN'T valid.

Comment: Keep Windows and your dual-boot configuration. You'll need Windows for things like BIOS updates, or to run an application that has no equivalent under Linux. Also, vendors won't support you in any other configuration.

Comment: Thanks your all for your advice. I would go by @heynnema suggestion.